# How to work on a testing branch and in the meantime do not lose the fix you do in the master branch?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-branch

I am in this kind of situation:

```
* 079152c (HEAD -> testing) Finished the new footer
* a81cb78 created a new footer
* 9c87d16 made a change to data
| * a75d5cb (master) fixed matrix data
| * 7b6cdd9 made another change to data
|/
* aa97c17 MY NEW FIRST COMMIT
```

Now I want to keep working on the testing branch but in the same time, I need also to update usually the master branch (which is my production branch). The problem is that every time that I make changes into the master, the testing branch stays the same. You could say, merge the master in the testing but in this way I will lose the progress I made in the testing.

Do you have any suggestions or insights?

Comment: you shouldn't lose your work from a merge. It's just that, a MERGING of the two branches, not replacing one with the other. So your theory is correct; once changes are applied to master, you need to merge or rebase master into your testing branch to realize those changes.

Comment: I agree with @user2051770. But to clarify something, you could either merge `master` into `testing` or rebase `testing` *onto* `master`. (Which maybe is the same as saying rebase `master` *into* `testing`, but to avoid confusion that isn't a commonly used phrase when talking about rebasing, since you'd have to reverse the order of the branches...)

Comment: Thank you guys this is much clearer now. So I guess I just have to solve many conflicts.